# C#側からすでに開いているEdge画面を操作する方法についてご教示願います。

Tags: c#, dom

C#側からすでに開いているEdge画面を操作する方法についてご教示願います。

**やりたいこと**

①すでに開いているEdge（複数画面）から、一つの必要な画面を特定する
②Edge画面のDOMを取得する
③Edge画面の項目の値を検証し、間違ったら、該当項目に色を付ける
④C#からEdge画面の遷移を発生させ、必要なデータを取得してから、
　元のEdge画面に戻る。
⑤Edgeの画面でのボタン押下（Link　押下）イベントを検知し、
　押下するタイミングに合わせて、C#側で処理を行わせる

Selenium WebDriverから操作しようとしたが、既存Edge画面を一回閉じて
WebDriverからEdgeプロセスを新規で起動して、必要な画面を開かなければならない。

（現在の調査では）WebDriverからは【やりたいこと①】を実現できませんでした。

**質問**

1. SeleniumWebDriverから既存Edge画面を閉じずに、そのままキャッチして、
   DOMを取得し、更に、該当項目に背景色つけることは可能でしょうか？
2. 他にネイティブ部品、もしくは、サードパーティ製の部品で、
   やりたいことを実現できる方法はあるでしょうか？
3. セキュリティの側面からして、そもそも、EdgeはIE11（mshtml.dll、
   SHDocVw.InternetExplorer等で操作する）のように外部操作できないでしょうか？

Comment: 重複になりますが、マイクロソフトのコミュニティーにも質問させて頂きます。

Comment: 色を変えるとかは無理では？ 操作ならUIAutomationとかで出来るかも。[【2017年8月版】起動中のMicrosoft EdgeからタイトルとURLを取得するC#コード](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=9085), [ARIA and UI Automation in Microsoft Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/accessibility/build/aria-and-ui-automation), [PowerShellのUIAutomationは複雑怪奇なり](https://qiita.com/mima_ita/items/3f2aa49fceca7496c587), [Edge 拡張機能のインストール](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/lang-ja/docs/installing-the-edge-extension)

Comment: なお、色んな環境関連で直ぐには動かせないのですが、こんなのがあります。[microsoft/WinAppDriver](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver), [WinAppDriverのサンプルを動かすまで](https://qiita.com/do-gugan/items/f65ddf44e45f34a2e201), [Appium を使った Windows ネイティブアプリケーションの UI テスト自動化](https://qiita.com/yuuhu04/items/5a96608ad96eccee34a0), [WinAppDriver UI Recorderを試してみました。](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=10504)

Comment: もしくは、これを試してみるとか。[IE モードで Microsoft Edge を使用する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/deployedge/edge-ie-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. SeleniumWebDriverから既存Edge画面を閉じずに、そのままキャッチして、
>      DOMを取得し、更に、該当項目に背景色つけることは可能でしょうか？

Seleniumの開発途中に実現できていた時もあったようですが、ブラウザ個別の特定モード/構成時のみなので、「実現不可能」状態のようです。
[Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8344776/9014308)
[Allow webdriver to attach to a running browser #18](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/18)

その特定モードは、Chrome/Firefoxや次の?Edgeでは、デバッグポートを有効にして起動したブラウザと通信して操作が出来るという、これのことかも。
[Microsoft Edge DevTools Protocol Clients](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/devtools-protocol/0.2/clients?view=azurermps-5.0.0)
[How to connect Selenium to an existing browser that was opened manually?](https://cosmocode.io/how-to-connect-selenium-to-an-existing-browser-that-was-opened-manually/)
[デスクトップ版 Firefox のデバッグを行う](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_Desktop)

他に古い版数のSeleniumの機能に、こんなのがあるようです。
[Selenium Remote-Control](https://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) / [Selenium 1 (Selenium RC) - Selenium Documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp)

> 2. 他にネイティブ部品、もしくは、サードパーティ製の部品で、 やりたいことを実現できる方法はあるでしょうか？
> 3. セキュリティの側面からして、そもそも、EdgeはIE11（mshtml.dll、
>      SHDocVw.InternetExplorer等で操作する）のように外部操作できないでしょうか？

コメントで紹介した[【2017年8月版】起動中のMicrosoft EdgeからタイトルとURLを取得するC#コード](https://www.ka-net.org/blog/?p=9085)の方法で、DOMのオブジェクト([IHTMLDocument2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752574(v=vs.85)), [IHTMLDocument3](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa752541(v=vs.85))等) が取得できましたし、単純なページで IHTMLDocument2::fgColor により文字色を変えるとかが出来ました。

細かい要素の検索とか変更は、IHTMLDocument3のオブジェクトを取得して操作した方が良いのでしょう。
C++での話ですが、こんな記事があります。
[MSHTML / ドキュメントとエレメント - EternalWindows](http://eternalwindows.jp/browser/mshtml/mshtml01.html)

IHTMLDocument3オブジェクト取得は、紹介先のIHTMLDocument2オブジェクト取得ルーチンの中で使っているGUIDをIHTMLDocument3のものに変えることで出来ます。
GUIDは [open-watcom-v2/bld/w32api/lib/uuid.c](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/blob/master/bld/w32api/lib/uuid.c) とか [mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/libsrc/mshtml-uuid.c](https://github.com/Alexpux/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/libsrc/mshtml-uuid.c) から調べてください。

ただし、Edgeの１つのウィンドウに複数のタブがあって、表示してから時間が経過した場合、アクティブでないタブの情報は取れなくなっていました。
1ウィンドウ1タブにするよう注意しておいた方が良いでしょう。

なお新しいEdgeは来年に出るそうで、しかも勝手にモードが切り替わるようなので、今上記のことが出来たとしても、何か不具合が起こる可能性は大きいですね。
[Chromiumベースの「Microsoft Edge」には「IE mode」あり](https://www.itmedia.co.jp/news/articles/1905/07/news050.html)
[ChromiumベースのMicrosoft Edge、2020年5月から切り替え開始か](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/20190718-860627/)

Comment: 返事が遅くなり申し訳ありません。回答ありがとうございます。
IHTMLDocument3を使用して、うまくEdgeをコントロールすることができました。長らく、色々ヒントもご教示頂き、大変ありがとうございます！